# laravel 5 simple ajax retrieve record from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I retrieve data using ajax? I have my ajax code that I've been using in some of my projects when retrieving records from database but dont know how to make it in laravel 5 because it has route and controller.

I have this html

```
<select name="test" id="branchname">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select first branch</option>
    <option value="1">branch1</option>
    <option value="2">branch2</option>
    <option value="3">branch3</option>
</select>

<select id="employees">
    <!-- where the return data will be put it -->
</select>
```

and the ajax

```
$("#branchname").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "employees",
        type: "post",
        data: { id : $(this).val() },
        success: function(data){
            $("#employees").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

and in my controller, I declared 2 eloquent models, model 1 is for branchname table and model 2 is for employees table

```
use App\branchname;
use App\employees;
```

so I could retrieve the data like (refer below)

```
public function getemployee($branch_no){
    $employees = employees::where("branch_no", '=', $branch_no)->all();
    return $employees;
}
```

how to return the records that I pulled from the employees table? wiring from routes where the ajax first communicate to controller and return response to the ajax post request?

any help, suggestions, recommendations, ideas, clues will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: im a newbie in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, add following entry in your `<head>` section of your `Master Layout`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

This will add the `_token` in your view so you can use it for `post and suchlike` requests and then also add following code for global ajax setting in a common `JavaScript` file which is loaded on every request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

So, you don't need to worry or add the `csrf_token` by yourself for methods who require this `_token`. Now, for a post request you may just use usual way to make an `Ajax` request to your `Controller` using `jQuery`, for example:

```
var data = { id : $(this).val() };
$.post(url, data, function(response){ // Shortcut for $.ajax({type: "post"})
    // ...
});
```

Here, `url` should match the `url` of your route declaration for the employees, for example, if you have declared a route like this:

```
Route::post('employees/{branch_no}', 'EmployeeController@getemployee');
```

Then, `employees` is the `url` and return `json` response to populate the `select` element from your `Controller`, so the required code for this (including javaScript) is given below:

```
$.post('/employees/'+$(this).val(), function(response){
    if(response.success)
    {
        var branchName = $('#branchname').empty();
        $.each(response.employees, function(i, employee){
            $('<option/>', {
                value:employee.id,
                text:employee.title
            }).appendTo(branchName);
        })
    }
}, 'json');
```

From the `Controller` you should send `json_encoded` data, for example:

```
public function getemployee($branch_no){
    $employees = employees::where("branch_no", $branch_no)->lists('title', 'id');
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'employees' => $employees]);
}
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: I followed your instruction but still it gives me "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: error says missing argument for "getemployee" and im sure its the "$branch_no" argument. how can i get the sent id from the ajax post request and send it to the getemployee controller for a query?

Comment: Oops! My mistake, updated the answer, check `$.post(url+'/'+$(this).val(), function(response){...});`

Comment: now the select box is populated with an option that has a text of NaN

Comment: Try `employee.id` & `employee.title` inside `$.each(response.employees, function(i, employee){...})`, I made a mistake :p

Answer (score 1):

First check url of page from which ajax call initiates

`example.com/page-using ajax`

In AJAX
 
If you call `$.get('datalists', sendinput, function())`
You are actually making GET request to 
`example.com/page-using ajax/datalists`

In Routes
`Route::get('page-using-ajax/datalists', xyzController@abc)`

In Controller Method

```
if (Request::ajax())
    {
        $text = \Request::input('textkey');
        $users = DB::table('datalists')->where('city', 'like', $text.'%')->take(10)->get();
        $users = json_encode($users);
        return $users;
    }
```

In Ajax Success Function

```
function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html = html + "<option value='" + data[i].city + "'>";
    };
    $("#datalist-result").html(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your route:

```
Route::post('employees', [
    'as' => 'employees', 'uses' => 'YourController@YourMethod'
]);
```

Ajax:

```
Change:
url: "employees"
to:
url: "/employees"
```

Comment: I use @The Alpha code guide and integrate your route but still it return me "http://juliver.laravel.com/employees 500 (Internal Server Error)n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jQuery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jQuery-2.1.3.min.js:4n.each.n.(anonymous function) @ jQuery-2.1.3.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ main.js:60n.event.dispatch @ jQuery-2.1.3.min.js:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jQuery-2.1.3.min.js:3
jQuery-2.1.3.min.js:4 POST http://juliver.laravel.com/employees 500 (Internal Server Error)|"

Comment: error says missing argument for "getemployee" and im sure its the "$branch_no" argument. how can i get the sent id from the ajax post request and send it to the getemployee controller for a query?